# Android - Push notification blank when not on top of the bar

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a small issue with android push notifications

If there are 3 Notifications and only one of these displays the title and the message. The one which is on the top of the bar. If anyone has any idea what might be the issue please let me know

Refer image on this link, this is how i am able to receive notifications 
http://postimg.org/image/3z4a21ssp/

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            //.setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            //.setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");


    //Added Try catch in case the old code doesnt work !
    try{
        //chgpk: Added this code to get bigger notification window
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(extras.getString("title"));
        inboxStyle.bigText(message);        
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
        }

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyleEx =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyleEx.setBigContentTitle(extras.getString("title"));
        inboxStyleEx.addLine(message);
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyleEx);
    }


    String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");     
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    MY_NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    //mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());


}
```

Also Code from DOT NET IS

```
 WebRequest tRequest;
        //tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create(vANDR_PN_url);

        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData =
            "collapse_key=score_update&"
            + "time_to_live=108"
            + "&delay_while_idle=1"
            + "&data.message=" + value
            + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString()
            + "&data.title=" + contentTitle
            + "&data.redirect_to_page=" + vredirect_to_page
            + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";

        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LogFilePath, Environment.NewLine + "sResponseFromServer >> " + sResponseFromServer);
        if (sResponseFromServer == "Error=InvalidRegistration") {
            mStatus = "error";
        }

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are setting texts for the bigStyle but not for the default (small) view.

Set all the texts:

```
// Small - default style
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
        .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
// Big style
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(extras.getString("title"));
    inboxStyle.bigText(message);        
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the notification builder :

```
 mBuilder.setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
         .setContentText(message);
```

The `BigTextStyle` is only displayed for the notification on the top. For the other notifications you must use `setContentTitle` and `setContentText`.

Comment: Thanks A lot Eran and MartinCR.. It worked :) :) Thanks a lot for a quick response .. You both rOck \m/

Comment: Eran this worked perfectly for me - and thanks for the explanation. Literally cleared everything up.