# Android push notification message not being displayed

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working with push notifications and I'm having trouble to understand a bug that I recently discovered.

I receive push messages just fine on Galaxy S4 Mini, Nexus 4, Galaxy Note 2, MOTO E and MOTO G.

But on Galaxy S5, I receive the push notification, I can see the message on status bar, but when I pull down the screen, the message is not there.
I see my image but I not seeing the message itself.

Does anyone have a clue about this problem?

Code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
    .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(message)
    .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
    .setSound(alarmSound)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(appName);
for (String notification : notifications) {  
    inboxStyle.addLine(notification);  
}  
nBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle); 

nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
nBuilder.setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent);

mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
```

Comment: So the fact that you see the message means GCM has actually successfully sent the message to your device and your device received it. How about try storing the message into a variable to see if you can display it later?

Comment: Yes, GCM successfully sent all messages. They are stored in local DB and I check that it IS there. And in all other devices shows the messages, but Galaxy S5 no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Eran (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25608914/3050951) and @MartinCR (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25608962/3050951) I was able to solve the problem.

The push notification message was blank on Nexus 4 (with lollipop) and Galaxy S5. So in my code I changed:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
    .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(message)
    .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
    .setSound(alarmSound)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

To:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(appName)  // <--- add this
    .setContentText(message)   // <--- and this
    .setTicker(message)
    .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
    .setSound(alarmSound)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

And now works just fine in every device.